# C# : instantiate a List, given a reference to a Type

Tags: c#, list

Suppose that, in C#, `myType` is a reference to some `Type`.
Using `myType` only, is it possible to create a `List` of objects of `myType` ?

For example, in the code below, although it is erroneous, I'd like to instantiate via

`new List <myType> ( )`  .

```
using System ;
using System.Reflection ;
using System.Collections.Generic ;

class MyClass
    {
    }

class MainClass
    {

    public static void Main ( string [] args )
        {

        Type  myType  =  typeof ( MyClass ) ;

        List < myType >  myList  =  new List < myType > ( ) ;

        }

    }
```

Comment: There's a more obvious error in your code: List<myType> = new List<myType>(); needs to be: List<myType> myList = new List<myType>();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do so using Reflection:

```
Type typeList = typeof(List<>);
Type actualType = typeList.MakeGenericType(myType);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(actualType);
```

Comment: Actually, I think you have a slight mistake here. you are creating instance of List<MyClass>, so you should cast to <code>var obj = (List<MyClass>)Activator.CreateInstance(actualType);

Comment: This proposed solution refers to "MyClass" -- I want to achieve the solution without referring to "MyClass", but, rather, using "myType", only.

Comment: Substitute `typeof(MyClass)` with `myType`, and you have your solution. Obviously you'll have to get rid of the cast in the third line, though, and use reflection to work with the created list - there's no other way if you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: I updated my answer. That's what I get for not proofreading it before posting.

Comment: Looks as if this will work for me ... thank you, Andy, and thanks to everyone else, too.

Answer (score 2):

[How to dynamically create generic C# object using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-object-using-reflection)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason to use

`List<myType>'
instead of`
List`

Essentially you're code wants to store objects whose type is not known at compiletime, in a collection (list).

I'd say, if you were planning on making this production code, either use List or use inheritance and store a list of the base classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection, but since the type of the returned list is not known at compile-time, the code *using* the returned list must access the members through a *loosely-typed* interface.

This won't result in faster or maintainable code over just using a List.

The better solution is to create a List<*interface*> where <*interface*> is a strongest *common* interface or base class of all of the types you could put in the list at run-time. At least that way, you aren't having to convert back and forth from object when working with the list members, and you'll have some compile-time validation of the sorts of things you're putting in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because `myType` is not known at compile time and you can't manipulate this list in your code. You could use reflection though to create an Array.