# Using JavaScriptSerializer Deserialze array of generic object in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, javascriptserializer

I am calling rest API from a loop and my object name is being decided at runtime. I am able to use reflection here for one object but how to get list of object?

```
  foreach (CloudDBTableList table in cloudDBTableList)
            {                
               string uri = string.Format(table.URI, "1-Jan-2011");
               string result  = _dataPullSvcAgent.GetData (baseURI + uri);


               string tableClassType = table.TableName + ", " + namespacePrefix;//namespacePrefix is same as assembly name.
               Type t = Type.GetType(tableClassType);
               JavaScriptSerializer jsonDeserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//t is only type of object whereas below method returns List<t> how to put it?
               var objectList = jsonDeserializer.Deserialize(result, t);

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackoverflow Rocks. Found answer from this question(though below question was bit dfferent from mine):-

[How to dynamically create generic C# object using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-object-using-reflection)
I modified my code like this:-

```
 foreach (CloudDBTableList table in cloudDBTableList)
            {                
               string uri = string.Format(table.URI, "1-Jan-2011");
               string result  = _dataPullSvcAgent.GetData (baseURI + uri);


               string tableClassType = namespacePrefix + "." + table.SchemaName + "." + table.TableName + ", " + namespacePrefix;//namespacePrefix is same as assembly name.
               Type t = Type.GetType(tableClassType);
               JavaScriptSerializer jsonDeserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
               var L1 = typeof(List<>);
               Type listOfT = L1.MakeGenericType(t);
               var objectList = jsonDeserializer.Deserialize(result, listOfT);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonDeserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<CloudDBTableList > list= jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<List<CloudDBTableList>>(cloudDBTableList);
```

Comment: Actually, from CloudDBTableList, each row is giving me different C# Class names, and URI, I am calling those URI, and URI is returning me List of <object> of that class name, but how should i create List<t> in above code is my question.

Comment: @Sutikshan Dubey I see, in that case I'll let someone else answer your question but my impression is that you can't to that. The only way -that I know of- to do something like that is just have a List<object> because List<T> has to be the same type of T

Comment: yes in single iteration all T of List<T> will be of same type. in each iteration, it will return List<T> where T is of type created from info on row of CloudDBTableList table.

Comment: finally found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-object-using-reflection