# Create repository instances on the fly with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, repository-pattern

For a given repository interface `IRepository<T> where T: Base` and a bunch of classes that inherit `Base` (for instance, `Text`) how do you create instances of a provider that implements `IRepository`, for instance `JsonRepository<T>` with `Text` as `T` `(JsonRepository<Text>)` and run methods on it?

I'd like to use reflection with a `for` or `foreach` to create instances of repositories for all the classes inheriting `Base` and perform some data management functions on them.

What I want to avoid - if you had 100 classes inheriting `Base` class you obviously wouldn't go creating instances manually in code and then running it?

Comment: It sounds to me like you have completely the wrong idea here. Data management functions? That doesn't sound like OLTP me to me, which is really the only place that repositories are useful. If you're doing bulk data management or ETL, not so much. Don't let your abstractions pin you down into only one way of looking at a problem.

Comment: I am fuzzy on what you are asking here. Are you saying you already have 100 classes that inherit Base and you want get instances of those classes via reflection so you don't have to hard code the 100 class names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151470/95573):

Modified to your example:

```
var d1 = typeof(JsonRepository<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(Text) };
var makeme = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);
```

Comment: Why do you assume the constructor is parameterless?

Comment: Because most data sources have a connection string or a path to file or some indication where the source is.

Comment: this looks promising but still requires hand coding typeof(Text)...preferably I'd like to have a foreach that would enumerate those types that inherit Base

Comment: Yes, you would need to create a loop and just use the types of all `Base` types you want to create.  Let me see if I can find an example

Comment: This question could help [Getting all types that implement an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26733/95573).  Then just loop through the types and use the type instead of `typeof(Text)`

Comment: @SwDevMan81: I'm not assuming anything. It could go either way. You didn't even address that possibility at all.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 you pointed me into the right direction and i'm posting my code that I got out from all of this as my own answer below but accepting yours.

Answer (score 0):

With @SwDevMan81's help and some reflection I managed to hack together this and it actually works perfectly:

```
var type = typeof(Base);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));

var jsonProviderClass = typeof(JsonContentProvider<>);
var xmlProviderClass = typeof(XmlContentProvider<>);

    foreach (var t in types) {
        Type[] typeArgs = { t };
        // get XML provider
        var xmlGenericProvider = xmlProviderClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        object xmlProvider = Activator.CreateInstance(xmlGenericProvider);
        // get JSON provider
        var jsonGenericProvider = jsonProviderClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        object jsonProvider = Activator.CreateInstance(jsonGenericProvider);
        // methods to run
        MethodInfo xmlMethod = xmlGenericProvider.GetMethod("GetContent", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        MethodInfo jsonMethod = jsonGenericProvider.GetMethod("Update");
        // get content from XML provider
        var result = xmlMethod.Invoke(xmlProvider, new object[] { string.Empty });
        // enumerate XML content items
        foreach (var item in ((IEnumerable)result)) {
            // update them via JSON provider
            object[] parametersArray = new object[] { item };
            var update = jsonMethod.Invoke(jsonProvider, parametersArray);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You currently use a generic constraint but why not use the 'new' constraint which denotes the generic type has a public parameterless ctor i.e.

```
IRepository<T> where T: Base, new
```

Which would then mean you could call:

```
abstract class ctor()
{
    IRepository rep = new T();
}
```

Now how you apply this may be through a base abstract class or you could simply return the rep instance by means of a propfull... It's upto you.

I have to admit your question is a little fuzzy so please excuse if this is not what you are getting at.

Comment: That wont work, you would only be able to create instances of the `Base` class.

Comment: But Base could be an interface/abstract class

Comment: It certainly could, but its not an `IRepository` inferface like in your example

Comment: In your example, `T` derives from `Base` and you can create a `new` instance of it (if it has a parameterless constructor).  It says nothing about `T` implementing `IRepository`

Comment: Hmm yes I see what you mean... Okay my answer is not going to cut the mustard.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I'm reading his question right. I would need a bit more of a concrete psuedo code to answer more clearly (I'll re-read now)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11240/discussion-between-paul-sullivan-and-swdevman81)