# Instantiating a generic class through reflection / typename

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

For example, I have a class, that looks like:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is create an instance of a Repository via reflection.

For example:

```
var typeName = "Customer"
var type = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetType(typeName);

//obviously, this isn't valid...
var repository = new Repoistory<type>();
```

Is something along these lines possible?

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection

Comment: `.GetType(string);` takes the full type name, with namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var repository  = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(type));
```