# instantiate a generic class using reflection

Tags: c#, generics

<sup>[**NOTE:** I don't believe this question is a duplicate of the one linked above, as I explain in the UPDATE below.]</sup>

Is there any way to define/instantiate a generic class using reflection?

So I have a bunch of classes, each of which owns an instance of a generic class that shares the type of its owner:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    T Owner { get; set; }
    public GenericClass(T owner) { Owner = owner; }
}
public class MyClass
{
    private GenericClass<MyClass> myGenericObject;
    public MyClass() { myGenericObject = new GenericClass<MyClass>(this); }
}
```

This works, but of course I have to explicitly specify "MyClass" as the argument in the GenericClass definition. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
private GenericClass<typeof(this)> myGenericObject; // Error: invalid token
```

Is there anyway to dynamically specify the type of the generic object at compile time, based on the containing class?

---

**UPDATE:** After reading the answers from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423655/instantiating-a-generic-class-through-reflection-typename) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection), I learned that I could instantiate a local variable like so:

```
var myGenericObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(this.GetType()));
```

but, of course, the `this` keyword is only available inside a method (so, for example, I could put this line of code in the constructor of `MyClass`). But I cannot use this approach to define an *instance* variable (i.e., `myGenericObject`, in the code above). Is there any way to specify a generic instance variable dynamically?

Comment: Did you try: Activator.CreateInstance<T>(). Its built in.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection

Comment: Generic class can only have generic instance field.

Comment: @AlexDenysenko: thatnks for the tip; I'll take a look at the generic version of CreateInstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your update, you can pass any `Type` to `MakeGenericType`. For example, the following also works:

```
var myObject = new MyClass();

var myGenericObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MyClass)), myObject);

Console.WriteLine(myGenericObject.GetType());
```

Outputs:

```
ConsoleApplication1.GenericClass`1[ConsoleApplication1.MyClass]
```

`myObject.GetType()` also does the same thing:

```
var myGenericObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(myObject.GetType()), myObject);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the point is I don't want to have to explicitly specify the Type. I want it specified dynamically at compile time.

Comment: What on earth does "dynamically at compile time" mean? Do you mean you just want to get rid of the <> from your syntax when writing programs? In that case make a static factory `public static GenericClass { public Create<T>(T owner) { return new GenericClass<T>(owner); } }` then you can call `GenericClass.Create(myObject)` and the compiler will infer the type.

Comment: Or do you really just mean "I want to make a GenericClass where the type argument is the type of it's owner", in which case you could write `public static GenericClass { public object Create(object owner) { return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(object.GetType()), object); } }` then you can write `object myObject = new MyClass(); object gc = GenericClass.Create(object)` and be confident that `gc.GetType() == typeof(GenericClass<MyClass>)` even though the compiler forgot everything about `myObject` except for the fact it's an `object`.

Comment: (You're right that my "dynamic/compile time" comment was very poorly worded. Sorry for the confusion.) Your second comment is really getting at what I was searching for. You had a couple typos so it didn't compile at first, but essentially that's the solution I was looking for. Now the only question is: do I lose out in terms of type-safety by declaring `gc` as an `Object` rather than a `GenericClass`? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is static built in construct for that:

```
Activator.CreateInstance()
```

Look at the overloads.

UPDATE

```
public Type FakeType { get; private set; }
public T CreateInstance<T>() where T : SomeEntityBase
{
     return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(FakeType);
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out that there is also a generic version: Activator.CreateInstance<T> http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx

Comment: I did already =)) look at the comments to the question

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how to use the generic version of CreateInstance, as the sample code in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx) doesn't actually use the construct.

Comment: I updated the answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what are you looking for but can try with inheritance:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    T Owner { get; set; }

    public GenericClass(T owner) { Owner = owner; }
}

public abstract class MyClassBase<T> where T : MyClassBase<T>
{
    protected GenericClass<T> MyGenericObject { get; private set; }

    protected MyClassBase() { MyGenericObject = new GenericClass<T>((T)this); }
}

public class MyClass1 : MyClassBase<MyClass1>
{
    public MyClass1() { }
}

public class MyClass2 : MyClassBase<MyClass2>
{
    public MyClass2() { }
}
```

Comment: interesting approach, but it doesn't seem to get around the need to specify the `Type` argument (in your case, to `: MyClassBase<MyClass1>`), whereas I was looking for a way to do so dynamically.