# Generic with reflection type

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

My actual code looks like this:

```
Myclass component = go.GetComponent<Myclass>();
```

I would like to make it more dynamic using reflections, so I tried the following

```
Type component = Type.GetType("Myclass");
object componentInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(component);
componentInstance = go.GetComponent<component>();
```

For the last line I get the following error

> The type or namespace name 'component' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there way to make this work?

Comment: Did you post the exact code you have? If yes - then class `component` is not referenced

Comment: For this to work, you need to invoke the method dynamically as well, constructing it with generic parameters first.

Comment: You cannot pass a type instance in as a generic parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post:

[How to dynamically create generic C# object using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection)

Shows exactly what you need.

Comment: Except any mention at all of `MakeGenericMethod`.