# C# - Class To String And Back (No XML)

Tags: c#, string, class, reflection

How can I convert my `Class1` or class of object to a `String` and then convert the `String` back to a type that I can use for instantiation ?

Something like that:

```
// class to string:
Type type1 = myObject.GetType();
string text = type1.ToString();

// and then back
Type type2 = Type.Parse(text);
// type2 should reflect the same type as type1
```

To do that with enums is really easy and nice. So I would like to have that with classes. I also want to **avoid** using serialization and XML. I don't want to serialize objects but **JUST** to remember the class I need to instantiate for an object.

Comment: why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: So your goal is to save the CLASS name to a string and not serialize or persist the data in the instanced class? :S

Comment: do you mean just remember the name of the class? myClassInstance.GetType().FullName

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create generic C# object using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection)

Comment: Right, every question is a duplicate to "What is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just the `Type` you want, then:

```
Type type = ...
string s = type.AssemblyQualifiedName; // and store s
Type andBackAgain = Type.GetType(s);
```

Comment: Thank you. That is more or less what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

If serialization is not needed, the [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) method can be useful. There are a number of overloads - some work directly with strings (representing Types), and others with Type objects.

Of course, it *might* be convenient (or more extensible) to use a serializer that also stores the Type information.

Comment: Another possibility could be to just remember the Type object. Why the round-trip to a string?