# Creating an object of Generic Class with dynamically generated type

Tags: c#, class, generics, reflection, properties

I have a generic Class

```
public  class MyClass<T>
{
   public List<T> Translate(List<T> list, params string[] names)
           {
            //do something here,modify list and return list
       }
    }
```

Now i can easily create its instances like

```
MyClass<Employee> obj= new MyClass<Employee>(); OR
MyClass<Vehicle> obj = new MyClass<Vehicle>();
```

I can call my method like

```
    obj.Translate(Mylist of employee or vehicle type,"param1","param2")
```

But in my case i dont know the type T as its generated on runtime,see the code below

```
String classname = string.Empty;

if(Classtype == 1)
{
    classname = "Employee"
}
else if(classtype == 2)
{
    classname = "Vehicle"
}
```

I want something like below..so that i can creat an instance of this generic class

```
MyClass<typeof(classname)> empp = new MyClass<typeof(classname)>();

    empp.Translate(MyList,"param1","param2")
```

Please suggest,how can i do that.

Comment: Is it actually useful to you to have `T`, or do you just need the runtime `Type`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create generic C# object using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection)

Comment: @TimS.  
 Now i want to call my generic class's method How can i do something like Instance.Mymethod(parameters);

Comment: @gunr2171  
 Now i want to call my generic class's method How can i do something like Instance.Mymethod(parameters);

Comment: I believe that you should also describe how you are supposed to use the generic type in your future code.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici.. i have edited the code.. please have a look

Comment: Now, could you provide some details about the `Translate` method? Maybe describing what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All for the Help I was able to do it by this way

```
        var someType = Type.GetType("MyProject.Employee");
        var genericType = typeof(Convert<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { someType });
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

        string instanceType = instance.GetType().FullName;

        MethodInfo methodInfo = Type.GetType(instanceType).GetMethod("Translate");
        genericType.InvokeMember(methodInfo.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, instance, new object[] { lstEmp, "Name", "City" });
```

ishan

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
var someType = Type.GetType("MyProject.Employee");
var yourGenericType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { someType });
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(yourGenericType);
```

Note that Type.GetType(...) only works with the full namespace of a type, or even the full assembly qualified name if your class is not in the same dll as the code that is executing this.

Comment: So how the OP calls some method or access some properties of the instance **directly** without using `Reflection`? This is not really a perfect solution.

Comment: @Moeri, maybe use `Type.GetType(className)`?

Comment: If you want to access any <T>-independent properties you need to extract those to an interface. Otherwise you're stuck with reflection, like you say.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici in his example his classnames are only the actual class names, not the assembly qualified or full namespace names. But I'll add something to the post, good thinking. :)

Comment: @Moeri  Now i want to call my generic class's method How can i do something like Instance.Mymethod(parameters);

Comment: @KingKing  
 Now i want to call my generic class's method How can i do something like Instance.Mymethod(parameters);

Comment: @AlexFilipovici  
Now i want to call my generic class's method How can i do something like Instance.Mymethod(parameters);

Comment: @IshanArora that's **the most difficult thing** and I realized that requirement of yours at first right after reading the question, looks like all the dynamic stuff would involve some part of `Reflection`.

Comment: @KingKing.. Please help if you have some idea king

Comment: @IshanArora: please provide a full example on what you are trying to achieve, and I'll see what I can do. Because right now, two roads are open to call methods on dynamically resolved types: interfaces or reflection. But we would like to avoid reflection as much as possible, so we need to see your scenario if possible.

Comment: Hey Ishan. Seeing as your Translate method is also fully generic, you will have to use reflection. Can I ask: why do you need to pass the class names as strings? If you can avoid using strings for class names, this could become a lot simpler.

Comment: @Moeri.. i have found the solution .. please see below and mark it as answer:)

Comment: Hello Ishan. You are the only one who can mark it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public T CreateEmptyObject<T>()
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));;
}
```

To call it:

```
YourClassObject yourClassObject = CreateEmptyObject<YourClassObject>();
```