# Create an instance of C# generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class

```
class Class<T>
{
     public Class(T arg)
     {
         print(arg.ToString());
     }
}
```

Pls Correct me: How to create an instance from this generic class

```
Type t = typeof(Class<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
Activator.CreateInstance(t,"test");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class), [How to dynamically create generic C# object using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection)

Comment: Your code works fine as it is..

Comment: class Class<T>
{
     public Class(ref T arg)
     {
         arg = "test";
     }
}

How to be in this case?