# How do I get the properties from a subclass when I have the class but subclass name as a string

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, subclass

I have a method which gets the name of a sub class from an error message, as below

```
string jobDesc = getDtlName(serviceResponse.ErrorMessages[0].Error);
```

I have the Class and want to access the sub class properties but how can I do that when I only have the sub class name as a string.

Java have a method which works like this

```
Class myClass = Class.forName(jobDesc);
```

How can I do the same in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a working solution using Properties with the code below

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(UIStaticFieldErrors).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (property.ToString() == "Boolean " + jobDesc)
    {
         property.SetValue(errorSF, true);
    }
}
```

I get the properties of UIStaticFieldErrors in properties and then iterate through until I get a match for jobDesc, then I update that field to true. The variable errorSF is an instance of UIStaticFieldErrors.

Answer (score 0):

You can **get all loaded assemblies** using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`,
then get **all types** of these assemblies with `.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())`
then select the **one type** with the given name with `.Single(t => t.Name == jobDesc)`.

Keep in mind that `Single` throws an **exception** if not exactly 1 element matches the condition.
If you have **multiple types** with the same name (in different namespaces) you should use `Where` instead.
If there may be **no matching classes**, use `SingleOrDefault`, which returns `null` if there is no matching element.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Single(t => t.Name == jobDesc)
```

If the desired class is in the assembly that is **currently executed**, you can also use

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Single(t => t.Name == jobDesc)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I get an error 'System.Array does not contain a definition for SelectMany'

Comment: @user616076 you have to include the namespace `System.Linq`

Comment: Ok, when I ran it I get this error 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.' Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @user616076 what do the LoaderExceptions say?

Comment: @user616076 I have added another option for you, maybe this works better.

Comment: The LoaderException says 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. Thanks for the other option, I'll try it now.

Comment: Hi Domysee, I've just tried it and it throws this error 'Sequence contains no matching element'.

Comment: @user616076 then it seems that the type you are loading is not defined in the executing assembly.

Comment: @user616076 `GetAssemblies` tries to load all assemblies referenced in the project, also all dependencies. It seems that something references `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation`, but the assembly is not copied to the output directory.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and find what is referencing ServiceLocation and copy the assembly.

Comment: @user616076 this could happen with other assemblies too. If you know in which assembly the type you want to load is specified, you can select only this one using `GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.FullName = "YourAssemblyName").SelectMany...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this,

```
string jobDesc = getDtlName(serviceResponse.ErrorMessages[0].Error);
SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass();
// set some class values,

var classType = typeof(SomeClass );                   
PropertyInfo info = classType.GetProperty(jobDesc);
var propertyValue = info.GetValue(myClass, null);
```

You might need to do a minor changes as I haven't tested this solution,