# Runtime C# Create List<T> where T is unknown like List<o.GetType()>

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, types

I have a method for mapping DataTable to Class objects  i.e. EntityTypes.

I want to run some iteration foreach code like foreach entity in myContext map(Table[xyz]) however I have run into a problem .

I need to be able to perform something like this `List<GetMyEntityType>` or similar `List<typeof(Get.MyEntity)>`

**I am not trying to create an instance of the object, I am trying to simply use the TYPE of object as the Type T argument for my Methods and my list.**

I do not know the type parameter until runtime - I need to pass in the discovered Type T into the method . I have looked at the suggested link - and that creates an Instance of Type T, I do not need an instance of it I need to pass the Type as the T argument to my methods.

see code below :

```
List<EntityType> ets = GetEntityFromContext(new WorkContext()); 

    foreach (EntityType myEntityType in ets)
    {

    DataNamesMapper<myEntityType> mapper = new DataNamesMapper<myEntityType>();

    List<myEntityType> Jobs = mapper.Map(ds.Tables["Job"]).ToList();

//..... other code

    }
```

Comment: You can´t expect the **compiler** to infer the runtime which you provide at **runtime**. This means even if you could get the exact type of the list at **runtime**, at **compile-time** all you get is a non.generic list.

Comment: @SelmanGenc question has been edited. I am looking to use the type of an object where I don't know the type until runtime to pass that type as the T argument.

Comment: @Ken the duplicate answers your question ,you need to use reflection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection  or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class

Comment: @SelmanGenç that question wants "I want to dynamically create TaskA or TaskB using C# ". My question I do not want to create the instance , I want to just pass the discovered Type as a type argument  T . Is there something I am not understanding.

Comment: @Ken is this not creating an instance? `DataNamesMapper<myEntityType> mapper = new DataNamesMapper<myEntityType>();`

Comment: @SelmanGenç  it is an instance of the datamapper; where MyEntityType can be any that are in MyDbContext. mapper uses reflection, to match properties,'column names' In your example are you telling me that I can do Activator.CreateInstance(DataNamesMapper<makeme>)?

Comment: @SelmanGenç I might be looking at this the wrong way - this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class?noredirect=1&lq=1 might do what I need.