# System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'myObject' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myObject]'.'

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I need to create a generic list of T by reflection and add item of T to it by invoke a method "Add", but I have error.
this is my code:

```
public class myObject
{
    public object FieldValue { get; set; }
    public int ID_OpenField { get; set; }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type type = typeof(List<myObject>);

    var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

    myObject obj = new myObject() { FieldValue = "TextObjectValue", ID_OpenField = 1 };
    object[] o = new object[] { obj };

    list.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, o);            
}
```

the last line gives me this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'myObject' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myObject]'.'

Comment: Is there any reason you are using reflection at all?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: almost certainly practice... No one is *that* masochistic, not even me!

Answer (score 1):

You came pretty close, but `MakeGenericType` is being called with the wrong arguments.

This will work:

```
        Type type = typeof(List<myObject>);

        Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(myObject) };
              var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
// your code: var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
       var list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

        myObject obj = new myObject() { FieldValue = "TextObjectValue", ID_OpenField = 1 };
        object[] o = new object[] { obj };

        list.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, o);
```

Refer to [How to dynamically create generic C# object using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151470/95135) for more information.

Comment: @bama71: my pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating a `List<List<myObject>>`, because `type` is `List<myObject>`:

```
Type type = typeof(List<myObject>);

var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

You should be using `typeof(myObject)` instead:

```
var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(myObject));
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```